# Oauth2 YouTube "error" : "invalid_request"

Tags: youtube-api

I dont understand whats wrong with this function to get my authkey?
I only get this error called "invalid_request", does anyone have any ideas?
It seems like it dont understand my request?

//Innk

```
public partial class OAuth : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

string _clientID = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("***********");

        string _clientSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("******");

        string _redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

        string _code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("token");

        string url = "code=" + _code + "&client_id=" + _clientID + "&client_secret=" + _clientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + _redirectUri + "&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("accounts.google.com", 443);
        Stream netStream = client.GetStream();
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(netStream);
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("accounts.google.com");
        {
            byte[] contentAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url.ToString());
            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
            msg.AppendLine("POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1");
            msg.AppendLine("Host: accounts.google.com");
            msg.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            msg.AppendLine("Content-Length: " + contentAsBytes.Length.ToString());
            msg.AppendLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("Request");
            Debug.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(url.ToString());
            byte[] headerAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg.ToString());
            sslStream.Write(headerAsBytes);
            sslStream.Write(contentAsBytes);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Response");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslStream);
        while (true)
        {  // Print the response line by line to the debug stream for inspection.
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            Debug.WriteLine(line);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that anyone who is doing .NET development and wants to access the YouTube APIs use the [official client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2).

If you'd prefer not to use the client library for all operations, at the very least, I'd recommend using it to [handle OAuth 2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) for you, and then using the tokens it generates in the `Authorization` header of the requests you roll yourself.